# Selecting a node from within an XML document?

Tags: c#, fileinfo, xmlnode, selectsinglenode, innertext

So I have an xmlDocument and I need to check to see if a credit score was appended. To do this I am using xmlNodes.SelectSingleNode and then checking the innerText.

My issue is this: one of the nodes has an ID field in the actual node name. So I think C# is interpreting that as part of the node name.

```
 public void DeperPostAppend()
    {
        DirectoryInfo CompDir = new DirectoryInfo(FilePrep.CompletedDirectory);

          foreach (FileInfo File in CompDir.GetFiles())
          {
              // Load xml documents for sorting
              XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
              try
              {
                  xmlDoc.Load(File.FullName);
              }
              catch
              {
                  if (File.Extension != ".xml")
                      return;
              }

            //XmlNode auto = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq");
            XmlNode home = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//HomePolicyQuoteInqRq");
            XmlNode creditAuto = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq//PersPolicy//CreditScoreInfo//CreditScore");
            XmlNode creditHome = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//HomePolicyQuoteInqRq//PersPolicy//CreditScoreInfo//CreditScore");

                //if file is type home quote
            if (File.Extension == ".xml" && creditHome != null)
                {
                    if (creditHome.InnerText != "ERR" || creditHome.InnerText != "NOH")
                    {
                        DeperHome();
                    }
                }
                //If file is type Auto Quote
            else if (File.Extension == ".xml" && creditAuto != null)
                {
                    if (creditAuto.InnerText != "ERR" || creditAuto.InnerText != "NOH")
                    {
                        DeperAuto();
                    }
                }
          }

    }//end DeperPostAppend
```

//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//HomePolicyQuoteInqRq//PersPolicy//CreditScoreInfo//CreditScore

PersPolicy is where the issue is. the node looks like this on the document.

```
<PersPolicy id="AE4562BEE086A92470D4">
```

I want to ignore the id portion due to the fact that it changes every document and i have thousands of docs to process.

Comment: It shouldn't have any problem with attributes like your id field. Can you post a dummy version of your XML? Also can you get a node for this `//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//HomePolicyQuoteInqRq//` and if so does it become null for this `//ACORD//InsuranceSvcRq//HomePolicyQuoteInqRq//`?

Comment: Look at the top element document.  Does it (or any other element) have an `xmlns` attribute?  If so, this pseudo-attribute declares a default namespace different from the null namespace of your XPath.  That's why you are getting empty results.  Namespace `is` part of each element's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to use classes to handle the nodes as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;


/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>

public class PersPolicy
{
    XElement self;
    public PersPolicy(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public CreditScoreInfo CreditScoreInfo { get { return _CreditScoreInfo ?? (_CreditScoreInfo = new CreditScoreInfo(self.Element("CreditScoreInfo"))); } }
    CreditScoreInfo _CreditScoreInfo;

    public string PolicyNumber
    {
        get { return (string)self.Element("PolicyNumber"); }
        set { self.Element("PolicyNumber").SetValue(value); }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class CreditScoreInfo
{
    XElement self;
    public CreditScoreInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public string CreditScore
    {
        get { return (string)self.Element("CreditScore"); }
        set { self.Element("CreditScore").SetValue(value); }
    }
    public string CreditScoreDt
    {
        get { return (string)self.Element("CreditScoreDt"); }
        set { self.Element("CreditScoreDt").SetValue(value); }
    }
}
```